# Getting the last record id through procedure

Tags: php, mysqli, mysql-insert-id

I am new learner and trying to get the last inserted id of a record.

But here it's giving me the following error:

Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT @p_customerId' at line 1

Any idea how to fix this.

Thanks,

```
<?php
class MyConnection{ 
    var $db_host = '127.0.0.1';
    var $db_user = 'root';
    var $db_password = 'xxx';
    var $db_name = 'xxx';
    var $connection;

    function Connect(){
        $this->connection = @mysqli_connect($this->db_host, $this->db_user, $this->db_password) 
        or 
        die("Error: ".mysqli_connect_error());
        mysqli_select_db($this->connection, $this->db_name);
        mysqli_query($this->connection, "SET NAMES 'utf8'");
    }

    function Disconnect(){
        mysqli_close($this->connection);
    }

    function ExecSQL($query){
        $result = mysqli_query($this->connection, $query) or die('Error: '.mysqli_error($this->connection));
        return $result;
    }

    function LastInsertId() {
        return mysqli_insert_id();
    }
}

if (isset($_POST['btnSubmit'])) {
    $v_custname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['txtcustname']);
    $v_custphone = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['txtcustphone']);
    $v_custemail = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['txtcustemail']);

    $conn = new MyConnection();
    $conn->Connect();
    $conn->ExecSQL("CALL sp_customer('$v_custname','$v_custphone','$v_custemail',@p_customerId); SELECT @p_customerId;");
    echo $conn->LastInsertId();
    $conn->Disconnect();

}
?>
```

Here's the procedure;

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `sp_customer`(IN `p_customerName` VARCHAR(50), IN `p_customerPhone` VARCHAR(50), IN `p_customerEmail` VARCHAR(50), OUT `p_customerId` INT)
    LANGUAGE SQL
    NOT DETERMINISTIC
    CONTAINS SQL
    SQL SECURITY DEFINER
    COMMENT ''
BEGIN
INSERT INTO customer(CustomerName, CustomerPhone, CustomerEmail)VALUES(p_customerName, p_customerPhone, p_customerEmail);
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() as p_customerId;
END
```

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to execute multiple statements in one query.

Read this: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.multiple-statement.php

Of course, I don't know why you added `SELECT @p_customerId;` to the query... Your next line of code requests the last insert ID anyway. Why don't you just take that out and do a single-statement query?

Comment: I have removed that one and did some modification on the code but now its returning 0

I added another function:

 function LastInsertId() {
  $result = mysqli_insert_id($this->connection);
  return $result;
 }

And trying to get it through:
 $conn = new MyConnection();
 $conn->Connect();
 $conn->ExecSQL("CALL sp_customer('$v_custname','$v_custphone','$v_custemail',@p_customerId)");
 echo $conn->LastInsertId();

Comment: Oh, sorry...  Your function has already called `LAST_INSERT_ID()` and set it in the variable `p_customerId`.  So instead of calling `$conn->LastInsertId()`, can you just do a second query to do the `SELECT @p_customerId;`?